# Issues connecting to Docker MSSQL using pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, docker, odbc, pyodbc

I have pulled a docker image that runs an MS SQL from docker hub:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
docker run --name some-db -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Aamerge1234 -e MSSQL_PID=Developer -d -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

The container runs fine, I added a strong password as required.
This is the python code I am using to connect with the database using **pyodbc**:

```
import pyodbc 

server = 'localhost:1433' 
# database = '' 
username = 'sa'
password = 'Aamerge1234'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER='+server+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

I have omitted the variable database because mssql creates several.
I tried using the following ODBC drivers:

- ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
- SQL Server

However, it always returns error:

> OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (53)')

Comment: Is the Python code running on the Docker host, or inside a Docker container? If it's on the host have you tried `server = 'tcp:localhost,1433'` yet? If it's in a container have you tried `server = 'host.docker.internal,1433'` yet?

Comment: You might also try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning server = 'tcp:localhost,1433' works with 'DRIVER={SQL Server}'. If someone is trying to replicate it 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' does not work.
Please write it as an answer so I can select it as top answer.